# iPhone 6 App Resizing

Tags: ios, xcode

So I recently got my iPhone 6, and I was working on a project earlier. When the new device arrived, the application looked messed up. For example, I have UIWebViews on the app, and when loaded on the iPhone 6, it just appears as if it where the iPhone 5s screen with white around.

Please help!

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: Nope, I'm new to Xcode... Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Search autolayout and set constraints for the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode has an auto layout tool that allows you to add constraints to the objects that you add to your story board so that in the event of the app being displayed on a different screen size, it has the logic to intelligently place your objects and lay them out to fit the new screen size.

I'd start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

...but there's a wealth of good tutorials and youtube videos out there showing examples of good practice.